# Kotlin sort one List with key and Enum with key and order

Tags: kotlin, sorting, collections

I receive data from Request information as list **data** (List) below code. That data has a "key" parameter by which I want to sort it.

```
data class ApplianceSetting(
    @SerializedName("key") val key: String,
    @SerializedName("value") var value: Any,
    (...)
```

I have the required order in the *SettingsUtilEnum* and want to sort items by that.

After that, I can convert the list using map{} the ***data*** and use the function of Enum getSettingByMode() and get the list of Enum values. Then I will sort them and convert them again to List.
But that sounds too inefficient. Is there a better way.

```
enum class SettingsUtilEnum(
   var settingKey: String,
   override val order: Int = 99,
   var settingName: String = "",
) : AbstractOrderEnum {

FIRST_MODE("first.mode", 0),
SECOND_MODE("second.mode", 1),
(...)
UNKNOWN_MODE("", 99);

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun getSettingByMode(settingKey: String): SettingsUtilEnum? {
        return values().find { it.settingKey == settingKey }
    }
```

k

```
 private fun initDataObserver() {
    (activity as FavouriteActivity).viewModel.applianceSettings.observe(activity as FavouriteActivity
    ) { data ->
        (controlRecyclerView.adapter as FavouriteAdditionalControlsAdapter)
        val adapter = (controlRecyclerView.adapter as FavouriteAdditionalControlsAdapter)
        // public final var data: List<ApplianceSetting>

        // old code:
            // data.settings
        adapter.data = sortAndGetControlModes(data)

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

// TODO: sortAndGetControlModes
private fun sortAndGetControlModes(data: ApplianceSettingsList) =
    data.settings.map {
        getSettingByMode(it.key)
            ?: UNKNOWN_MODE.apply {
                // If in future new modes are added -> put them as tail
                settingKey = it.key
            }
    }.sortedBy { it.order }
    // error i need to return again List<ApplianceSetting>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using sortedBy and as comparator I am using received value (order) from getSettingByMode(), if item is not found (null) I give him order value of 99 and put it on tail position:

```
    private fun sortAndGetControlModes(data: ApplianceSettingsList) =
         data.settings.sortedBy { 
             getSettingByMode(it.key)?.order ?:99 
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare keys with theirs ASCII values you can just use `sortBy { it.key }`

If you want to expand possibilities of comparison you can use function `sortedWith` with passing custom `comparator` as argument.

Comparator used to compare its two arguments for order. Returns zero if the arguments are equal, a negative number if the first argument is less than the second, or a positive number if the first argument is greater than the second.

**Example:**
You can use it like that if you want to sort by integer value of `key` parameter:

```
data.settings.sortedWith { a, b ->
      when {
            a.key.toInt() < b.key.toInt() -> -1
            a.key.toInt() > b.key.toInt() -> 1
            else -> 0
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @KirillNay, I had achieved the task (you can check how into my answer :) ). I had a Specific String valued key and external order parameter into the Enum named - order (int).